# SwiftUI: .ignoresSafeArea() odd behavior?

Tags: ios, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                LocationPickerView()
                    .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width, maxHeight: geometry.size.height)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to have my LocationPickerView() take up the entire screen regardless of the orientation of the device. A LocationPickerView() is a custom view I built:

```
struct LocationView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView()
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

However, I have a problem. The safe area is not being ignored. At first glance, I thought this was because the frame was already set by a "constant" value from geometry.

So, I thought I would flip the order of when I ignore the safe area and when I set the frame. This only resulted in a much weirder configuration. At first, the view does take up the entire screen. However, when I change the device to another orientation, the view stays the original height and width it was without updating, despite using `GeometryReader`.

What is happening here? I am certain this is valid behavior, but I don't understand why it is and how to fix it. I am trying to make things as simple as possible and thought I would add the frame and safe area options in my main struct, in an attempt to keep that code out of every view.

This feels like an easy fix, but I can't figure it out.

Edit:

If I change the code of LocationView to the following:

```
struct LocationView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let arView = UIView()
/* Changing UIView to an ARView
   blocks the screen from updating on orientation change... really odd! */
        arView.backgroundColor = .brown
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) { }
}
```

It works! However, if I simply change `let arView = UIView()` to `let arView = ARView()`, it doesn't work!

This has to be something with `ARView`.

Comment: When interfacing with UIKit I prefer using a UIViewController, so I can "pin" the `view` to the edges. that allows SwiftUI to have full control of the frame

Comment: Ok. However, it seems like the problem is my ‘ArView’ and nothing with UIViewRepresentable.

Comment: To be expected, some views are more adaptable than others but pinning it should work.

Comment: Hello, I’ve got to be honest, I don’t really know if that will actually work. The discussion with @son basically makes me think there’s something odd going on with ‘ARView’ itself.

Comment: Hi there, I'm back again. I tried using a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and set its view to an `ARView` — this did not really change the outcome. In fact, I tried setting the constraints for the view, if this is what you meant by "pinning" to the edges.

Answer (score 2):

The `geometry.size` is equal to `screen - safeAreaInsets`. So, `LocationPickerView.frame` in your example will take the entire screen size with safeAreaInsets. `ignoresSafeArea()` is meaningless. I think you don't need `GeometryReader` since your LocationPickerView is the root view of WindowGroup and it doesn't have any parent views.

```swift
LocationPickerView()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
```

**UPDATED**: replaced UIViewRepresentable with `ARView`

```swift
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    let arView = ARView()
    arView.backgroundColor = .brown
    return arView
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I will take a look at this. I will say, for an intuitive reason, that I specifically remember changing my code from what you have to using GeometryReader. Unfortunately, I forget why.

Comment: GeometryReader returns a flexible preferred size to its parent layout. Maybe you were used in the nested view of `LocationPickerView`. Take your time.

Comment: Well, my intuition was right. I tested your code with `LocationPickerView` having no implementation just like in my original post, just to be extra clear. Yep, it doesn't work. In fact, it works with returning `some UIView` which is extra odd.

Comment: I found a person with the same issue, but no solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/j5s7tn/how_to_make_arview_fullscreen_uiviewrepresentable/

Comment: Alright, I tested more things. See my original post under "Edit" — this is really weird.

Comment: That's weird. I've changed `UIViewRepresentable` to ARView and it still works as expected. I checked that ARView is still inherited from UIView so, it will have an init function with frame. In my opinion, it should work. Are the any distinctions between  `LocationView` and `LocationPickerView`? Or just a TYPO here? I saw you implemented `LocationPickerView` in the WindowGroup, but you showed up `LocationView` code.

Comment: Sorry, `LocationPickerView` and `LocationView` and not typos. `LocationView` is the actual `UIRepresentable` implementation with an `ARView` being used. `LocationPickerView` is just another SwiftUI view that is in another file. Right now, it's just holding a `LocationView` but it will eventually hold a `LocationView` with extra UI over top of it. Basically, the end result will be an `ARView` with UI over it. I will have to take a look at what you did as soon as I can. Do you mind sharing your code? @loremipsum mentioned using a `UIViewController` above but is that the best way? I don't know.

Comment: I tried `ARView`. Generally, it's presenting a black screen now, maybe I missed some configurations. Then I changed the background color and debugged the UI hierarchy. It filled the entire screen. You can check the attached image.

Comment: Right, but does it fill the entire screen when you change orientations? iPad simulator is a good example to test it.

Comment: gotcha, I saw the issue. It's because of ARRenderView - a subView of ARView. It seems like ARRenderView hadn't constraints to fit its superview. The black background is this one. Its superView (ARView) still has correct frame, while its not... weird.

Comment: Yes, the orientation is the problem. I've managed to figure out how to make it cover the whole screen without a problem earlier. If you look at my third piece of code in my original post, it shows the issue. It's really all about rotating the device after the app has been launched. That's the problem.

Comment: Hello, I was looking at this again. Still haven't gotten very far. How did you find `ARRenderView`? I can't find much information on that. I found `ARViewBase`, which is what `ARView` inherits from (which happens to be a type alias to `UIView`).

Comment: It showed up on the debug UI screen. I am trying to force ARRenderView to call layoutSubviews(), but no luck, I will tell you then if I find a workaround on this issue.

Comment: Hi there, I really appreciate your help! This one has really got me stuck. Just so weird! :)